# (C#) Issue with retrieving data from Azure SQL Database

Tags: c#, rest, azure, http-headers, azure-sql-database

I have been working on a simple c# app (using Azure SQL Database ). First my app saves an name and then by clicking on show all persons, it should retrieve all the saved names from the database. For some reason my code fails to retrieve the names from the database ,so when i click on show all persons, it does not react, could you help me to fix that ?

---

From My rest Controller class:

```
 public List<Person> getPersons()
        {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            String sql = "SELECT * from users";

            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    persons.Add(new Person(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1)));
                }
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in getPersons(): " + e.Message);
            }

            return persons;
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code of show all persons button click? Are you getting any error? Did you verify if `getPersons` method code works fine?

Answer (score 1):

If we test connecting to Azure sql on local, we need to add the client IP to the [Azure sql Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal) to allow local to access the Azure sql.

[image]

If the connection is not open, we need to **open the connection** before retrieve data from Azure sql database. We also could set the breakpoint to get more detail error info.

```
try
   {
      if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)

      {
          connection.Open();
      }
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
      SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
         persons.Add(new Person(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1)));
      }
  }

catch(Exception e)
{
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in getPersons(): " + e.Message);
}

  return persons;
```

Answer (score -1):

First make sure the names are actually getting saved in the database.

Second check if your controller is executing successfully without throwing an exception. In your try catch, you log the exception and still return an empty persons list. So you wouldn't know what the error is on the client side.

Third is to make sure you have enabled Azure services to access your Azure SQL instance. This can be done via the Azure portal.

Hope this helps.